# Hubspot API - how to loop to get all deals

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, hubspot

The loop just keeps returning the same JSON-object, but I change the offset... does anybody know what's wrong?

I'll just write the whole function to be sure, probably not very dry.

```
function getDeals (api_key) {

  //get the right spreadsheet & sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Dealname", "Dealstage", "Close date", "Amount"]);

  //set up API variables

  var offset = 0;
  var queryParams = '&limit=250&offset=' + offset + '&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=amount'
  var _url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey=' + api_key;
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  //set up functions for call
  var apiCall = function(url, endpoint){
    var apiResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + endpoint,options);
    var json = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
    return json
  };

  var filterDeals = function (url, unfiltered_deals){
    var i = 0;
    while (unfiltered_deals.status !== "error" && i < (unfiltered_deals.deals).length) {
      if (unfiltered_deals.deals[i].properties.dealstage.value == "closedwon") {
        var dealname = unfiltered_deals.deals[i].properties.dealname.value;
        var dealstage = unfiltered_deals.deals[i].properties.dealstage.value;
        var closedate = new Date((unfiltered_deals.deals[i].properties.closedate.value)*1000);
        var amount = unfiltered_deals.deals[i].properties.amount.value;
        var deals = [dealname, dealstage, closedate, amount];
        // Append Hubspot data to Spreadsheet
        sheet.appendRow(deals);
      }
      i++;
     }
    if (unfiltered_deals.hasMore) {
      offset = unfiltered_deals.offset;
      var newDeals = apiCall(url, queryParams);
      filterDeals(_url, newDeals, offset, queryParams);
    } else {
      return
    }
  }

   //Api call to get deals  
  var dealCall = apiCall(_url, queryParams);
  var filteredDeals = filterDeals(_url, dealCall);

};
```

i call this function with the API-key.

Comment: is it `closedwon` or `closedown`, in your if statement inside your loop.

Comment: it's "closedwon"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you always get the same JSON parameter is you never update you variable `queryParams` with the new offset value. In your code snippet:

```
if (unfiltered_deals.hasMore) {
      offset = unfiltered_deals.offset; 
      var newDeals = apiCall(url, queryParams);
      filterDeals(_url, newDeals, offset, queryParams);
    }
```

you get the new offset value i.e `offset = unfiltered_deals.offset;`. But you need to update your queryParams by reinitializing its value like so

```
  if (unfiltered_deals.hasMore) {
      offset = unfiltered_deals.offset; 
      queryParams = '&limit=250&offset=' + offset + '&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=amount'
      var newDeals = apiCall(url, queryParams);
      filterDeals(_url, newDeals, offset, queryParams);
    }
```